# How do I return a value from a function in a batch file?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I have the following batch file

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /f "delims==" %%J in (File_List.txt) do (
call :setDate %%J MYD
echo/Date is: %MYD%
)
endlocal &goto :eof

:setDate
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS
echo %1
echo %~2
set NAME=%1
set NAME=%NAME:~-11%
echo %NAME%
echo %~2
endlocal&set %2=%NAME%&goto :eof
```

but with File_List.txt containing 
    file2012-05.csv

I get

```
file2012-05.csv
MYD
2012-05.csv
MYD
Date is:
```

How do I actually get the function setDate to return the value I want?

Comment: I want to return %NAME%. I was experimenting with %1 and forgot to change it back. I have changed the code back to the original now, still doesn't work.

Comment: Your error is in the line "echo/Date is: %MYD%" as you are in a for cicle you have to use !MYD! instead of %MYD%

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The batch interpreter evaluates `%MYD%` at parse time, and at that time it's empty. That's why you have [Delayed Expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html). Change this line:

```
echo/Date is: %MYD%
```

to this:

```
echo/Date is: !MYD!
```

and it will work like you want, because then it tells the interpreter to evaluate `MYD` at run-time.

Comment: I suppose (almost) the only time you really want delayed expansion is if you're using endlocal at the end of a function scope and need to inline the "returning" of a value.

Answer (score 32):

As I don't understand from your script what you want to achieve, I reply (for completeness) to the original subject: returning a value from a function.

Here is how I do it:

```
@echo off

set myvar=
echo %myvar%
call :myfunction myvar
echo %myvar%
goto :eof

:myfunction
set %1=filled
goto :eof
```

Result is:

```
empty 
filled
```

Comment: I'm not sure why, but [Simon Sheppard](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html) use it as `Set "%~1=filled"`. Anyway, **this** is the actual answer to the question asked in the title.

Comment: To get promised output the 2nd code line should be `set myvar=empty`. And it is good practice for having multiple function in a batch file to finish every function with `exit /b 0`, not with `goto`.

Comment: The problem with this approach is that ever environment variable created into :myFunction will be public. A function must be a black box, the internal variables must be internal. This is made with SetLocal/EndLocal commands.